# Python subprocess module, command window popup issue

Tags: python, module, subprocess, pycharm

I am trying to execute:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('cmd.exe /k ipconfig')
```

Python Idle is giving "command window popup" output, but if I execute the same in Pycharm editor, I am not getting "command window popup" output. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCharm uses Output Console instead of separate windows.
You can see you program output there (subprocess output as well).

The only requirement is to setup run configuration in 
`Run` - `Edit Configurations` menu.

You can check `Emulate terminal in output console` flag if you have any troubles with output's look in output console (wrong encoding etc.), but don't forget to stop process manually in this case.

Switch project interpreter to `pythonw.exe` in order tohave your console command in separate window.

Comment: Thanks for the response Roman Mindlin. Even though I checked Emulate terminal in output console...I am unable to get the output in command window using Pycharm editor.

Comment: What you see in output console?

Comment: The result what we got when we run 'ipconfig' command in command window....the same it is showing in Run window of Pycharm..But my requirement is I need command window popup with ipconfig result...

Comment: For better understanding execute in python idle and observe the result and execute the same in Pycharm and observe the result...

Comment: Thank you for clarifying your question. Just switch project interpreter to `pythonw.exe` and you'll have your console command in separate window.